# self-created FLV player does not play videos on production server or other machines

Tags: flash, video, video-streaming, flv

I created a flash video player using Flash CS3. I exported the player to html and it works fine on my PC.

The problem is that it does not play on other machines. It also does not play when the page is opened from our website (web server is on a different machine, hosted), even when using my computer.

What could possibly be wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: is flv URL is passed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably got a bad path somewhere and the request for the video is returning a 404. In any case, this is the easiest thing to check and should be ruled out first for any data driven Flash application.

You need to check your HTTP requests. Firebug's net tab might suffice or you might want to try a stand alone web debugger. I use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/download/) even though it's not FOSS (it's cheap). Some of my Windows-using coworkers use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/).

Comment: I did have a bad path, in my swf file. The path to the flv was absolute. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction ;)

Answer (score 1):

How exactly are you embedding the flash player in your HTML page? Have you checked to make sure that the paths to the .flv file are valid? Also, do you have a webserver installed on your PC, or are you simply viewing the HTLM using your system's file browser?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that if your web server is using Windows Server 2003, by default, it does not recognize the FLV mime type.  You actually have to add it in.

http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/194/tn_19439.html